# Click Event Not working below the x-axis line in chart Js (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, bar-chart, ng2-charts

I am using Chart JS ,try to make click event in bar chart labels,click event not working below the x axis and I try some other achieve this in click event in canvas ,but it not working

HTML code:

```
<div style="width:700px; height: 250px;" >
      <canvas id="myChart" style="width:400px; height: 200px;" #mychart
      (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
      
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

Chart.ts:

```
 this.canvas = this.mychart.nativeElement; 
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        let subPerf = new Chart(this.ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'My Dataset',
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132,0.4)",
              borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
              fill: true,
              data: [10, 12, 6, 5, 11, 7, 9]
            }]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            onClick: event => {
              console.log(event)
              const canvasPosition = getRelativePosition(event, subPerf);
              // Substitute the appropriate scale IDs
              const dataX = subPerf.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);
              console.log(dataX)
              const dataY = subPerf.scales.y.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.y);
              // let point = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(event, subPerf.chart);
              // let xIndex = subPerf.scales['x-axis-0'].getValueForPixel(point.x);
              // let label = subPerf.data.labels[xIndex];
              // console.log(label + ' at index ' + xIndex);
            },
            scales: {
              xAxis:{
                grid: {
                  display: false,
                  drawBorder: false
                },
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: "ss",
                },
              },
              yAxis:{
                grid: {
                  display: false,
                  drawBorder: false,
                },
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: "jj",
                },
              },
            },
          }
        });
```

Inserted Image ,Green area  cannot able to click

[image: Inserted Image ,Green area cannot able to click]

version
Angular-14
ng-charts-4.0.1
chartjs-3.9.0
Nodejs-16.15.1
Thanks In Advance

Comment: is there an error in the browser console? when clicking outside of the chart?

Comment: and is the function `chartClicked`being called?

Comment: @winner_joiner Is no error in the console and no event were trigged in that X-Axis tick triggered  and chartClicked  were not called

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` of the chart.js options won't work, these events seems to work only *"inside"* of the chart-area. If you check the documentation it doesn't state this explicitly, but if you read all the modes you see, that they are **all** geared to getting position/items/... relative to data-point ([link to documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.1.1/configuration/interactions.html)).

the only way would be over a eventlistener. something like this *(I would keep it ease for debug reasons)*:

```
<canvas ... (click)="chartClicked($event)">
```

but I don't know much about Angular.